# Access user account via path (mywebsite.com/username) php

Tags: php, .htaccess, path

How can I make a feature in my website that allows to have links such as **mywebsite.com/steven123** and redirect to the page with **steven123's** account info (like Facebook and Twitter do)?
I though of 2 ways of doing this:

1. Do it with .htaccess file that will modify the path in such a way that the username will be a GET parameter of a php file, but Im not sure how to accomplish this.
2. When the user enters the link it will redirect to a 404 error page in which I will have a php file that compares the string after the slash to a database with usernames and returns error if not found or the account itself.
   Now the second method seems to be an unorthodox and unnatural way of solving this problem. Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first method

Follow this Tutorial https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect
Then create a file to handle the username and access the database to get the information of the user. Then render the HTML using the data fetched by the database .
P.S This is how almost all the web frameworks work

Comment: Thanks! It sorted things out :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache the follow rules of .htaccess may help.

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/user.php?username=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then you must have a file user.php in the root of the site. And the work of this file is to show the user info and/or any other you want to show. You can you $_GET['username'] to the username.